# how to refill data after reloading page in php

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I'm stuck at one point .I have a php form and after filling all details, user have to press submit button . If data does not submitted properly then I am reloading the page .

so My question  is .

> I want to set all previous values  entered by user into respected
>   fields without request method.

how can i achieve this?

What I have done so far

My **user.php**

```
<?php
$name = '';

if(isset($_REQUEST[name]))
{
   $name = $_REQUEST[name]; 
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
   $name = $_POST["txtname"];

  header('Location:user.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>');

}

?>

<hrml>
<body>
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST">
<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

**apply_now.php**

```
    <?php 
    $CLASS__BL = 'apply_now_bl';
    require_once('apply_now_bl.php');

    ?>

    <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="input-label">Full Name: *</label>
                      <input name="txtname" id="txtname" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?= @$page_bl->full_name; ?>">
                    </div>
</form>
```

**apply_now_bl.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('admin/db_lib/candidates.php');
require_once('includes/general_include.php');

$page_bl = apply_now_bl();
page_load();

class apply_now_bl
{

    var $full_name = '';

function page_load()
    {
        $this->obj_candidates = new candidates();

        if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {
            $this->submit_data();
        }

    }

    function submit_data()
    {
        $this->full_name = get_post_val("txtname"); 
        $this->obj_candidates->full_name =  $this->full_name;

        redirect(apply_now.php); //common function for page redirect
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want actually

Comment: I want to get back posted data without request method.

Comment: means this is one type of profile form and you want to fetch data once save in database right?

Comment: no dear Soubhagya  Kumar i want to when i submit form data and get in php side then data reject by server validation then go back as it page and show message (e.g Please select valid type of file). right their fill entered data.

Comment: oh got it give me 5 mins

Comment: what do you mean by **If data does not submitted properly** are you validating from client side or server side ?

Comment: Ravi I mean if data is reject into server validation then i do redirect it page. When entered data is back to filled in form. It problem once solution is we pass data in request method but i need of other way. how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to redirect through php header location . because action is blank and that means it will redirect to user.php(current page) once form submit.

so below is the updated code

```
<?php
$name = "";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST["txtname"];
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `No i need of redirect page Like<?php
$name = "";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST["txtname"];
    header('location:file.php');
}
?>`